# How to accept custom Content-Type from the client and change it to text/xml in SOAP webservice?

Tags: java, spring, nginx, soap

is there a way to accept custom Content-Type - `application/health.message+xml; charset=utf-8; type=HEALTH_CHECK` from the client and change it to text/xml in SOAP webservice?
The application was developed in Java (Spring Boot WebService - JAX-WS)
According to the search in internet there is a way to resolve the problem via nginx config.

The exception which we are getting

```
UnsupportedMediaException: Unsupported Content-Type: application/health.message+xml; charset=utf-8;  type=HEALTH_CHECK Supported ones are: [text/xml]
```